# How do I translate this C# lambda into VB.net?

Tags: c#, vb.net, lambda, hangfire

I'm having difficulty translating a C# statement into VB.  I don't know if this is a lambda, which I do use but I'm not that expert with, or a separator, which I understand even less.  According to Microsoft, the C# ['=>' symbol](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/lambda-operator) can be used in those 2 different ways.

The line of C# code I'm having trouble with is:

```
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(() => TextBuffer.WriteLine("text"), Cron.Minutely);
```

It is from the Startup.cs file in the [sample hangfire.mvcApplication project](https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire.Samples).  This is the full Class:

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseSqlServerStorage("DefaultConnection");
    app.UseHangfireDashboard();
    app.UseHangfireServer();
    RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(
        () => TextBuffer.WriteLine("Recurring Job completed successfully!"), 
        Cron.Minutely);
}

the TextBuffer.WriteLine reference is:

public static void WriteLine(string value)
{
    lock (Buffer)
    {
        Buffer.AppendLine(String.Format("{0} {1}", DateTime.Now, value));
    }
}
```

This is what I tried, which is not really accurate; I tried a lot of variations:

```
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(Function() TextBuffer.WriteLine("text"), Cron.Minutely)
```

And the syntax error I get in Visual Studio is:

```
Expression does not produce a value
```

I went to the definitions for AddOrUpdate and saw the following overloads, but I'm not sure which is the proper selection to use nor how the syntax would look once I pick the proper overload.

```
Public Shared Sub AddOrUpdate(methodCall As Expression(Of Action), cronExpression As Func(Of String), Optional timeZone As TimeZoneInfo = Nothing, Optional queue As String = "default")
Public Shared Sub AddOrUpdate(methodCall As Expression(Of Action), cronExpression As String, Optional timeZone As TimeZoneInfo = Nothing, Optional queue As String = "default")
Public Shared Sub AddOrUpdate(methodCall As Expression(Of Func(Of Task)), cronExpression As String, Optional timeZone As TimeZoneInfo = Nothing, Optional queue As String = "default")
Public Shared Sub AddOrUpdate(methodCall As Expression(Of Func(Of Task)), cronExpression As Func(Of String), Optional timeZone As TimeZoneInfo = Nothing, Optional queue As String = "default")
Public Shared Sub AddOrUpdate(recurringJobId As String, methodCall As Expression(Of Action), cronExpression As String, Optional timeZone As TimeZoneInfo = Nothing, Optional queue As String = "default")
Public Shared Sub AddOrUpdate(recurringJobId As String, methodCall As Expression(Of Action), cronExpression As Func(Of String), Optional timeZone As TimeZoneInfo = Nothing, Optional queue As String = "default")
Public Shared Sub AddOrUpdate(recurringJobId As String, methodCall As Expression(Of Func(Of Task)), cronExpression As String, Optional timeZone As TimeZoneInfo = Nothing, Optional queue As String = "default")
Public Shared Sub AddOrUpdate(recurringJobId As String, methodCall As Expression(Of Func(Of Task)), cronExpression As Func(Of String), Optional timeZone As TimeZoneInfo = Nothing, Optional queue As String = "default")
Public Shared Sub AddOrUpdate(Of T)(methodCall As Expression(Of Action(Of T)), cronExpression As String, Optional timeZone As TimeZoneInfo = Nothing, Optional queue As String = "default")
Public Shared Sub AddOrUpdate(Of T)(methodCall As Expression(Of Action(Of T)), cronExpression As Func(Of String), Optional timeZone As TimeZoneInfo = Nothing, Optional queue As String = "default")
Public Shared Sub AddOrUpdate(Of T)(methodCall As Expression(Of Func(Of T, Task)), cronExpression As Func(Of String), Optional timeZone As TimeZoneInfo = Nothing, Optional queue As String = "default")
Public Shared Sub AddOrUpdate(Of T)(methodCall As Expression(Of Func(Of T, Task)), cronExpression As String, Optional timeZone As TimeZoneInfo = Nothing, Optional queue As String = "default")
Public Shared Sub AddOrUpdate(Of T)(recurringJobId As String, methodCall As Expression(Of Action(Of T)), cronExpression As Func(Of String), Optional timeZone As TimeZoneInfo = Nothing, Optional queue As String = "default")
Public Shared Sub AddOrUpdate(Of T)(recurringJobId As String, methodCall As Expression(Of Action(Of T)), cronExpression As String, Optional timeZone As TimeZoneInfo = Nothing, Optional queue As String = "default")
Public Shared Sub AddOrUpdate(Of T)(recurringJobId As String, methodCall As Expression(Of Func(Of T, Task)), cronExpression As Func(Of String), Optional timeZone As TimeZoneInfo = Nothing, Optional queue As String = "default")
Public Shared Sub AddOrUpdate(Of T)(recurringJobId As String, methodCall As Expression(Of Func(Of T, Task)), cronExpression As String, Optional timeZone As TimeZoneInfo = Nothing, Optional queue As String = "default")
```

I just don't understand what the method is looking for or how to properly write it.

Comment: In C#, every method is a function with those that don't return a value having a type of `void`. In VB, methods that don't return a value are `Subs`, not `Functions`. The same goes for Lambdas, which are just anonymous methods. Just note that, when LINQ was originally introduced, VB did not support action Lambdas, i.e. `Subs`, but only value Lambdas, i.e. `Functions`. If you're using an older version of VB that doesn't support action Lambdas then you'll need to use a named method and create a delegate for that.

Comment: Nice explanation, thanks. I am using VS2017, so I suppose the older version caution doesn't apply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VB.NET has [two different lambda expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/procedures/lambda-expressions): `Function`, which returns a value, and `Sub`, which does not.

In this case, you want to use `Sub`, as your expression does not return a value.

```
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(Sub() TextBuffer.WriteLine("text"), Cron.Minutely)
```

Comment: Well, I don't feel so bad, because I actually tried what you wrote above, but I must have had some minor syntax issue - using your line above passes the checker.  Thanks!  I think I had 2 closing parenthesis, and so figured my whole line was wrong, but I had been quite close.  Your answer with @jmcillhinney's comment above clears it all up for me.  Learned something new tonight.  Nice link for me to study on the VB lambda's, too.